# Angular router: route not being tested by following path rule

Tags: angular-router, angular-router-guards

Given the following code:

```html
const LOCALIZED_PATHS: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'activities',
    canActivate: [CountryGuard],
    loadChildren: 'app/common/activities/index/global/activity-index.module#ActivityIndexModule'
  }
];

.
.
.

RouterModule.forRoot([
      ...LOCALIZED_PATHS,

      /** GLOBAL ROUTES */
      // New Module
      {
        path: 'activities/new',
        loadChildren: 'app/common/activities/new/activity-new.module#ActivityNewModule'
      }
      .
      .
      .
```

And the route `/activities/new`.

I expect the router to test the rules inside `LOCALIZED_PATHS`, and if it returns `false`, to test the next rule (`path: /activities/new`) and match.

What is currently happening - according to the flow of the program in the google dev console - is that it's first testing the rules given by the `ActivityIndexModule` and returning `false`, then testing the `canActivate` guard and also returning `false`, but finally not navigating to the `ActivityNewModule`.

What am I missing? Am I understanding correctly the flow in the console as it should be running given the program logic?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Once a matcher catches a route, routing is over. Guards are post-matching, so even if it returns `false`, the router won't continue to try to match with the next rule.